# Variable value changes depending if its the first or the second time it is executed

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a really specific problem I'm not even able of searching for similar issues.

I have the following variables

```
cm = np.array([[65, 4, 22, 24],
               [6, 81, 5, 8],
               [0, 11, 85, 19],
               [4, 7, 3, 90]])

proportions = [0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2]

n = np.sum(cm)
nisum = np.sum(cm, axis=1)
nsumj = np.sum(cm, axis=0)

p_i = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], 1])
p_ii = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], cm.shape[1]])
prod_ac = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], 1])
user_ac = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], 1])
overall_ac = 0

for i in range(cm.shape[1]):
    for j in range(cm.shape[0]):
        p_ii[i, j] = proportions[i] * cm[i, j] / nisum[i]

    if i == 0:
        p_i = np.sum(p_ii, axis=0)

    prod_ac[i] = ((proportions[i] / p_i[i]) * (cm[i, i] / nisum[i]))
    user_ac[i] = cm[i, i] / nisum[i]
    overall_ac += proportions[i] * cm[i, i] / nisum[i]
```

If I execute in the console of PyCharm the whole block of code, the result of prod_ac is wrong, it results

```
prod_ac
Out[215]: 
array([[  1.        ],
   [ 31.05      ],
   [  1.28787879],
   [  2.76442308]])
```

But if I inmediately execute again just the loop part of the code, the result of the prod_ac is ok:

```
prod_ac
Out[217]: 
array([[ 0.84252858],
   [ 0.90639122],
   [ 0.47056319],
   [ 0.60898115]])
```

No errors or warnings rise.

I'm guessing it is something with memory. Aparently if I execute all the lines at once the result is wrong. But if I execute the first part (from line 1 to the line before the loop), and aftwerwards I execute the loop, the result is fine.

All the other variables are created fine every time. It is just prod_ac with troubles.

Does anyone have any clue of where could be the issue?? I how could I manage to get the good result every time. This will be part of a function so I won't be able to execute by parts in the future.

thanks

Comment: maybe you can print some parts of the functions to see what step/variable causes the difference? Although that is what you would expect, you should verify loops are running with exactly same iterations and same inputs. Once you verify that, you could check if all variables are same in two runs before run starts. If that is also the case, then you should focus on the different parts of the loop.

Comment: For example, is `p_ii` exactly the same in different runs if you comment out everything after the second `for` loop (removing `if` and other lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a memory problem. Problem is in `p_i`

```
import numpy as np
cm = np.array([[65, 4, 22, 24],
               [6, 81, 5, 8],
               [0, 11, 85, 19],
               [4, 7, 3, 90]])

proportions = [0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2]

n = np.sum(cm)
nisum = np.sum(cm, axis=1)
nsumj = np.sum(cm, axis=0)

p_i = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], 1])
p_ii = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], cm.shape[1]])
prod_ac = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], 1])
user_ac = np.zeros([cm.shape[0], 1])
overall_ac = 0

for i in range(cm.shape[1]):
    for j in range(cm.shape[0]):
        p_ii[i, j] = proportions[i] * cm[i, j] / nisum[i]

    if i == 0:
        p_i = np.sum(p_ii, axis=0)
        print(p_i)

    prod_ac[i] = ((proportions[i] / p_i[i]) * (cm[i, i] / nisum[i]))
    user_ac[i] = cm[i, i] / nisum[i]
    overall_ac += proportions[i] * cm[i, i] / nisum[i]

for i in range(cm.shape[1]):
    for j in range(cm.shape[0]):
        p_ii[i, j] = proportions[i] * cm[i, j] / nisum[i]

    if i == cm.shape[1]-1:
        p_i = np.sum(p_ii, axis=0)
        print(p_i)

    prod_ac[i] = ((proportions[i] / p_i[i]) * (cm[i, i] / nisum[i]))
    user_ac[i] = cm[i, i] / nisum[i]
    overall_ac += proportions[i] * cm[i, i] / nisum[i]
```

would give

```
[0.16956522 0.01043478 0.0573913  0.0626087 ]
[0.20125753 0.35746154 0.15707358 0.28420736]
```

so that is causing the difference. And the reason is you are summing across the ith axis before the ith axis is completed. So it makes sense that it works the second time because this time the entire array was already ready so it can use values that would have been generated in the following iterations. How to solve this is up to you. One working example is below:

```
for i in range(cm.shape[1]):
    for j in range(cm.shape[0]):
        p_ii[i, j] = proportions[i] * cm[i, j] / nisum[i]

p_i = np.sum(p_ii, axis=0)

for i in range(cm.shape[1]):
  prod_ac[i] = ((proportions[i] / p_i[i]) * (cm[i, i] / nisum[i]))
  user_ac[i] = cm[i, i] / nisum[i]
  overall_ac += proportions[i] * cm[i, i] / nisum[i]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Your example's solution is exactly what I just did ten minutes ago, but without knowing that the problem was p_i. As you say, now I see clearly the problem with that sum inside the loop.